# How do you pass a parameter on awk command?

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I tried this but it does not seem to work. 
Please help thanks

```
 TEST_STRING= test

    echo Starting awk command
    awk -v testString=$TEST_STRING'
        BEGIN {

        }
    {
        print testString
        }
        END {}
    ' file2
```

Comment: Correct syntax is `awk -v testString="$test_string" 'BEGIN { ...`. Also, your assignment must not have a space if you intend it to work -- `test_string=test`, or `test_string=" test"` if you really want the leading space.

Comment: Also, in general, when saying something "doesn't work", it's best to describe exactly _how_ it fails.

Comment: (All-caps variable names in shell, by the way, are reserved by convention for environment variables and builtins; other variable names should have at least one lower-case character. Following this practice prevents namespace collisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here: You aren't actually assigning to `TEST_STRING`, and you're passing the program code in the same argument as the variable value. Both of these are caused by whitespace and quoting being in the wrong places.

---

```
TEST_STRING= test
```

...does not assign a value to `TEST_STRING`. Instead, it runs the command `test`, with an environment variable named `TEST_STRING` set to an empty value.

Perhaps instead you want

```
TEST_STRING=test
```

or

```
TEST_STRING=' test'
```

...if the whitespace is intentional.

---

Second, passing a variable to awk with `-v`, the right-hand side should be double-quoted, and there must be unquoted whitespace between that value and the program to be passed to awk (or other values). That is to say:

```
awk -v testString=$TEST_STRING' BEGIN
```

...will, if `TEST_STRING` contains no whitespace, pass the `BEGIN` as part of the value of `testString`, not as a separate argument!

```
awk -v testString="$TEST_STRING" 'BEGIN
```

...on, the other hand, ensures that the value of `TEST_STRING` is passed as part of the same argument as `testString=`, even if it contains whitespace -- and ensures that the `BEGIN` is passed as part of a separate argument.

Comment: Thanks! how about multiple parameters? awk -v testString=$TEST_STRING' testString2=$TEST_STRING2 BEGIN

Comment: @PhilipMorris, with multiple `-v` arguments: `-v testString="$test_string" -v testString2="$test_string2"`

Comment: if I pass it to a regex inside the awk command, does the regex read the value or the parameter name?

Comment: There's more than one way to refer to a regex inside an awk script. If you use relational expressions (`~` and `!~`) with variables dereferenced on the right-hand-side rather than constant regexes (`/foo/`), then you'll be able to treat variables passed in as regexes.

Comment: @PhilipMorris, ...to give you a more concrete example: `awk -v 'ext=gem' '$0 ~ ext { print }'`. That said, what you're asking there really should be its own question; we're getting rather far afield from the original topic.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help =)